# Stimulsoft report not load in MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, stimulsoft

I have tried to use `StimulSoftReport` in MVC 5. I have designed an .mrt file in stimulsoft designer. I have a view which will print the report.
This view file contains this code:

```
@using Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "چاپ قبض";
    Layout = null;
}
@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(
"MvcViewerReport",
new Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc.StiMvcViewerOptions()
{
    ActionGetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshot",
    ActionViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent" 

})
```

The print Action located in same controller as `GetReportSnapshot` and `ViewerEvent` . But when Print View shown. It just have toolbar of report viewer and doesn't show my reporter even I create a break point and I found that none of above actions called from the view.

here is the code of `GetReportSnapshot` :

```
public ActionResult GetReportSnapshot()
        {
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            dataset.ReadXmlSchema(Server.MapPath("~/Content/report/BillXmlFile.xsd"));
            StiReport report = new StiReport();
            report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/report/Report.mrt"));
            report.Dictionary.ImportXMLSchema(dataset);
            report.Compile();                        
            return StiMvcViewer.GetReportSnapshotResult(HttpContext, report);
        }
```

and here is the `ViewerEvent` code :

```
public ActionResult ViewerEvent()
        {
            return StiMvcViewer.ViewerEventResult(HttpContext);
        }
```

What is the matter ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problme fix by adding this part of code to assemblyBinding tag on web.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass data to the report. There is just Schema. Usually the DataSet is registered with RegData() method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know could you solve your issue or not? But I had recently problem same as you, I'm working with mvc 5.2.3, I googled but couldn't find suitable solution, so I guessed it's need to change .dll version.
I changed dll to Stimulsoft.Suite.2015.2.Retail and issue has been fixed.

Hope this is help to you.